# Photo Vignette Removal Tool (Jython, Python)

Tags: python, jython

I need to build code for this question.

1. First we need to understand what the vignette looks like in isolation, without the clutter of a beautiful scene. For this, a picture of a flat surface of a single colour that is evenly lit (such as a white wall or plain blue sky during mid-day) is obtained and used as a “vignette profile”. You are given the following vignette profile image.

   In this image, the pixels towards the center of the image have higher RGB values (i.e. 
   brighter pixels) than the pixels that are away from the center. The image is also black and 
   white, so red, green and blue values of any given pixel are the same. You must not modify 
   this image.
2. We need to use the vignette profile image from step #1 as a filter for our normal photos 
   captured by our camera so that the vignette can be removed. For this you need to divide 
   the photo image (with vignette) by the vignette profile image. As the pixels in the vignette image have RGB values that are smaller (darker) towards its edges, dividing the original image's corresponding pixels by a small number will make them brighter

These are the hints

Hint 1: This requires you to perform your operations on your images, pixel by pixel. I.e. you cannot do it in a single step.

Hint 2: The first challenge for you will be keeping the RGB values resulting from the division within the 0-255 range for each channel, as valid RGB values are between 0 (darkest) and 255 (brightest).

---

Edit:

Sample code:

```
def runA1(picture): myFile = pickAFile() picture = makePicture(myFile)

 myFile2 = pickAFile()
picture2 = makePicture(myFile2)


for x in range(0,getWidth(picture)):
    for y in range(0,getHeight(picture)):
      px = getPixel(picture,x,y)
      color = getColor(px)
      color = makeLighter(color)
      setColor(px,color)

for x in range(2,getWidth(picture)):
    for y in range(2,getHeight(picture)):
      px = getPixel(picture,x,y)
      color = getColor(px)
      color = makeDarker(color)
      setColor(px,color)



show(picture2)
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what you're tried, or considered trying? Is there something in particular you're stuck on? As it stands your question doesn't give any indication as to what specifically you need help with, apart from "Please give me the full solution to my homework question".

Comment: No-one is doing your homework for you, you must come up with specific questions regarding specific problems. Being too lazy to learn does not count!

Comment: @hochl: I was giving the benefit of the doubt and assuming the OP was just unfamiliar with StackOverflow's expectations... but you're right; the OP hasn't shown very much effort.

Comment: And it's good to help others nonetheless :) But in this case I think you're wasting your time. I wonder if the sample code is part of the assignment ...

Comment: @hochl: It looks precisely like someone tried to write Java in Python. (A `Picture.PixelGetter()` wouldn't be out of place here...)

Comment: Convolution filters are your friend, see this great writeup https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ed67/837642ec24f5d2269925dd619da02ad4b134.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't demonstrated that you've tried anything on your own, I'm only going to give hints as to what you should try.

1. Consider a single pixel represented as three integers, 0-255, in the form `(R,G,B)`. The corresponding pixel from the vignette mask has value `A`, again 0-255. Divide `(R,G,B)` by `A` and *multiply by 255*  to get the un-vignetted pixel `(RR,GG,BB)`. (Why do we need to multiply by 256?)
2. Decide what you want to do about `R,G,B` values exceeding `255`. What happens if the vignette value `A` is zero?
3. Do this for each pixel in the image, starting with the top row of pixels working left to right, then the next row down, and so on until you're done.

---

Incidentally, this kind of thing *is* a one-step operation in a language with first-class numerical matrix support - say MATLAB, Octave, **Numpy/Scipy**. Here's a MATLAB example:

```
processed_image = original_image ./ repmat(vignette_image,[1 1 3]) * 256
```

---

Edit 2:

Some comments on your sample code:

1. Your indentation is wrong - this code will not run. Maybe this got mangled when you pasted it into StackOverflow. Please fix it. In particular,

   - the `def` statement has to be on a line by its own.
   - `myFile2 =....` has to be indented from the def: statement.
2. `myFile1`, `myFile2` - these variable names could be more meaningful. (Which of these is the original photo? Which is the vignette mask? You could try calling these variables `original_file`, `vignette_file` instead. Ditto for `myPicture1`, `myPicture2`.)
3. Where are the comments in your code? It's hard to tell what your code does.

Apart from this, you need to post more code. Your example needs to be a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org). Right now your code example is not self-contained because to run it, we would also require the `getPixel()`, `getColor()`, `makeLighter()`, etc. functions. It's also not compilable due to indentation errors.

Comment: i've tried to make a program... but it doesn't seem right...

Comment: i'm pretty sure it's not right. but the answer must be look like this.

  def runA1(picture):
    myFile = pickAFile()
    picture = makePicture(myFile)
    
    myFile2 = pickAFile()
    picture2 = makePicture(myFile2)
    
    
    for x in range(0,getWidth(picture)):
        for y in range(0,getHeight(picture)):
          px = getPixel(picture,x,y)
          color = getColor(px)
          color = makeLighter(color)
          setColor(px,color)
    
blah blah blah

Comment: You haven't told us that. *Show us* what you've tried. (Paste code into your original question, [taking care to format it correctly for StackOverflow.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).) Then maybe we can help correct *your* code so that it works.

Comment: @user1335799: Don't put code in comments - as you can see the formatting gets mangled. Instead, edit your original question to include your sample code.

Comment: the code going to be in programming area. and i'm totally lost about this homework... if you give me your e-mail or something i will send you original file.

Comment: @user1335799 I edited your post so the sample code you tried to insert into my answer (!) appears after your original question. And we don't give advice in private here: we give all advice in public so that everyone (not just you) can benefit.

Comment: The sample code is not right. I think I need to write code from the start. there is an image but i can not upload...

Comment: I need to use two images, first one is using as filter, which is make second image lighter sides and normal in middle, it looks like gradation. i'm totally lost about this work....

Comment: We can't help you unless you put in more effort to show us a sample program that at least **compiles** or looks like it might compile.